# Python MQTT to publish multiple message with same topic

Tags: python, mqtt

I am trying to publish a multiple random data using mqtt to the broker. Below is the script for the publish part.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json, schedule, time, random

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("<broker address", 1883, 60)

def pub_message():
        tempreading = random.uniform(0, 100)
        pHreading = random.uniform(1,14)
        oxyreading = random.uniform(0, 100)


        data_string1 = str(oxyreading)
        data_string2 = str(pHreading)
        data_string3 = str(tempreading)

        msgs = [("randomdata", data_string1),("randomdata", data_string2),("randomdata", data_string3)]
        client.publish(msgs)

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(pub_message)

while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

client.disconnect()
```

I ran the script and there is error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqttpub.py", line 27, in <module>
schedule.run_pending()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 462, in run_pending
default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 75, in run_pending
self._run_job(job)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 129, in _run_job
ret = job.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 377, in run
ret = self.job_func()
  File "mqttpub.py", line 22, in pub_message
client.publish(msgs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 980, in publish
rc = self._send_publish(local_mid, topic, local_payload, qos, retain, False, info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1979, in _send_publish
utopic = topic.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I searched about the publish multiple message with mqtt but did not find any good reference. I also included my mqtt subscribe part for receiving the multiple messages. I did search about this part too but did not find any good reference.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from models import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import json

def on_connect(client, userdata, rc):
        print("connected with result code" + str(rc))

        client.subscribe("randomdata")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print "Topic:", msg.topic + " " + "Message:" + " " + "Value1:" + str(msg.payload1) + " " + "Value2:" + str(msg.payload2) + " " + "Value3:" + str(msg.payload3) 

        engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost/mydatabase')
        Base.metadata.bind = engine
        DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

        session = DBSession()
        # store message received into database
        raw_data = _Data(Value1=msg.payload1, Value2=msg.payload2, Value3=msg.payload3, time=msg.timestamp)
        session.add(raw_data)
        session.commit()


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("<broker address>",1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Does anyone have any experience doing it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think `client.publish()` will accept an array?

The doc's (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#publishing) don't mention anything about publishing multiple messages, you will have to call `client.publish()` once for every message you want to send.

You should also be calling `client.loop()` in your while true loop.

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    client.loop()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I found this while searching through the internet. http://nullege.com/codes/search/paho.mqtt.publish.multiple Thought that the same example will work. But anyway, do I have to put the client.publish function all before the schedule.every().minute function?

Comment: The `paho.mqtt.publish.multiple()` method is more for one off sending of multiple message as it builds and tears down a connection to the broker each time it's called. For this use case calling `paho.mqtt.client.publish` for each message makes more sense.